# How to Remove Edit text data before returning to that Activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-edittext

Say Activity **A** has a `Edittext`, on entering some information and on clicking a button in that particular activity it goes to Activity **B**.

On returning to Activity **A** by clicking back button from **B**, the content in the Edit text remains as such.. help me getting it erased.

Comment: just put `editText.setText("")` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that:

1) Remove `EditText` data before start ActivityB

2) Use `startActivityForResult` to launch your ActivityB and override `onActivityResult` in your ActivityA

3) Override ActivityA `onResume` method and remove `EditText` data inside that method. With this approach, your `EditText` data could be flushed even if you do not start ActivityB, so be aware of Activity lifecycle.

To do so, just do:

```
editText.setText("");
```

Comment: Note that doing this in `onResume()` also means any interruption e.g. incoming call will flush the data as well.

Comment: @adnanyousafch, Yep, you are right, I have edited my answer to be more precise

Answer (score 1):

just before calling `startActivity(intent)` method, reset it by setting the `editText.setText("");`

Answer (score 1):

before Intent set your `edittext to ("");`

```
EditText name = (EditText)findViewByid(R.id.edittext);
name.settext("Your Name");

Button send = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
     name.settext("");
         Intent activity_b = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
         startActivity(activity_b)
        }

    });
```

or you can also do

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
super.onResume();
name.settext(");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`editText.setText("");`

you can put above line of code in two different ways

1. If you want to make only edittext empty when ActivityA comes back from ActivityB then just put it before the line of code where you are starting ActivityB.

   `edittext.settext("");
   Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this, ActivityB.class);
   startActivity(intent)`
2. In `onResume()` if you want to cover all different scenarios. It will make edittext empty whenever that activity returns whether from another activity or from the background.

Hope it will help you.